React project using yarn berry "Module '~~~' or its type declaration not found." error
The vsc version is 1.94 and the typescript version is 5.6.2
error
I think there is a problem in .yarn/sdks/typescript/lib.
yarn
Does anyone know a good solution?
// tsconfig.json
{
  "name": "vite-project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc -b && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.13.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.13.0",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.59.0",
    "@tanstack/react-query-devtools": "^5.59.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.26.2",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.11.1",
    "@types/node": "^22.7.4",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.10",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.2",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.5.0",
    "eslint": "^9.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.1.0-rc.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.12",
    "globals": "^15.9.0",
    "typescript": "^5.6.2",
    "typescript-eslint": "^8.7.0",
    "vite": "^5.4.8"
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@4.5.0"
}


// vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import { resolve } from "node:path";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  cacheDir: "./.vite",
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": resolve(__dirname, "src"),
    },
  },
});



I tried updating the project's dependencies, but it didn't work.

No errors should occur
